# Validate Second field if First Field is filled

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am having 3 files browser and a text box for label for each file input type.

```
<label>Photo 1</label>
<input type="file" size="10" name="service_field[15]" id="15" class="{accept:'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|tif',messages:{accept:'Only jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp,tif files are allowed.'}} file">
<label>Photo 1 Title</label>
<input type="text" name="service_field[576]" id="576" class="txt" value="">

<label>Photo 2</label>
<input type="file" size="10" name="service_field[578]" id="578" class="{accept:'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|tif',messages:{accept:'Only jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp,tif files are allowed.'}} file">  
<label>Photo 2 Title</label>
<input type="text" name="service_field[577]" id="577" class="txt" value="">

<label>Photo 3</label>
<input type="file" size="10" name="service_field[579]" id="579"  class="{accept:'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|tif',messages:{accept:'Only jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp,tif files are allowed.'}} file" >    
<label>Photo 3 Title</label>
<input type="text" name="service_field[580]" id="580" class="txt" value="">
```

I am using jquery validator plugin with jquery.metadata.js.

I need to validate these input in such a way if a file is browsed then user have to input the label for that file.

Comment: FYI, your labels should either have a `for` attribute, or should enclose the field they refer to. That way, clicking on the labels puts the focus on the corresponding fields.

Comment: FYI (again) `jquery.metadata.js` is effectively obsolete. As of jQuery 1.4, [$().data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) can access JSON-encoded data attributes. Also, putting a json literal in a `class` attribute is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each of them with a div like so

```
<div>
   <label>Photo 1</label>
   <input type="file" size="10" name="service_field[15]" id="15" class="{accept:'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|tif',messages:{accept:'Only jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp,tif files are allowed.'}} file">
   <label>Photo 1 Title</label>
   <input type="text" name="service_field[576]" id="576" class="txt" value="">
</div>
```

Then you could do

```
$('.txt').siblings('[type=file]').bind('change blur',function(){//if it changes or loses focus
     if($(this).val().length){
          $(this).siblings('.txt').show();
     }else{
          $(this).siblings('.txt').show();
     }
})
.blur();//this is so it can be trigger every time you load the page,, comment out if you wish
```

I should have mentioned... I have not used that validation, so gave you an alternative which it does same thing :)